# Is there a clean and an optimal way to separate service configurations for Desktop and Mobile using Spring Boot in a cloud-based microservice?

Tags: spring-boot, device

Is there a clean and an optimal way to separate service configurations for Desktop and Mobile using Spring Boot in a cloud-based microservice? Such that the requests coming from Desktop or Mobile are processed by the same service but pulls different configurations based on device type. For e.g., on the Cart page, the wishlist display should be turned off for mobile but not for the Desktop.

One workaround is to duplicate the keys of the configurations by appending mobile or desktop to them (like `conf.display.wishlist=true` for desktop and `mobile.conf.display.wishlist=false`) and load values based on type by appending type to the key.

Comment: Any code sample? Not very clear

Comment: I've elaborated on with the example above. Please let me know if it makes the question clear.

Comment: A request is coming from a mobile or desktop is a client side attribute & not server side so when your server side is started, it doesn't have device information & also device info is going to vary request by request so in my opinion, there doesn't seem a way other than hard coding that you suggest ( At Spring Boot level ) . Also, you seem to be tweaking UI based on API response, why not tweak UI neutral to API response and by device type ( if that configuration is already fixed ) ? What you are asking seems a client side concern & not API side.

Comment: I need to enable/disable features based on these config keys and some features will be disabled on Mobile device.

Comment: I need to disable/enabling some processing on the backend of the basis of this key. This has nothing to do with the presentation layer.